# How to solve fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error

Hi I am new to swift i tried to develop sample app using UILabels and UITextfields and UIButton.When i click the button to navigate Viewcontroller to another Viewcontroller.It showing fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. at self.userText.delegate = self in viewdidload.

how can solve this please help me some one.

## Here is my Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet var userLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var pwdLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var userText: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var pwdText: UITextField!    

    @IBOutlet var loginButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func loginBtnAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstVC") as! FirstVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.userText.delegate = self
        pwdText.delegate = self

        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true

    }

}
```

Comment: your outlet connections are probably not correct. check them

Comment: Hello Shubhank, Thanks for replying.i am delete connections and reconnect    the outlet connections.still same error comming

Comment: please post the stack trace shown in the console or use **bt** command in console to output it.

Comment: If it is a sample, it must be small. You can mail your project at ankit8946@gmail.com and I will check.

Comment: Hi Ankit,I sent my sample app to ankit8946@gmail.com

Comment: Shubhank,I dont know how to use bt command in the console it showing fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your code and the FirstVC you have created is subclassed from ViewController, in fact it should be UIViewController and everything will work fine.